# C# Resource Array

Tags: c#, resources

I have a bunch of pictures I'm using in a C# project, and I'm trying to initialize them all for later use. There are over 50 of them and they all have the same name format Properties.Resources._#, where # is the picture number. What I'm trying to do is something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   pics[i] = Properties.Resources._i;
}
```

How would I go about embedding the index into the name?

Thanks, and happy holidays.

EDIT: Just realized that if I had a way to embed the index in the name, I could just have a function that returns the specific picture based on the number given, so that would work too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
 (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_" + i)
```

Note that each call will read a separate copy of the bitmap, and will take time.
If you use the images frequently, pre-loading them into an array will make your program *much* faster.

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Resources.ResourceManager'. RecourceManager.getObject("_" + i) works though. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user: No; I was.  Fixed; sorry.