# Accessing resources like array's elements

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resources, windows-forms-designer

I have two Resouces: **1.jpg**, **2.jpg**. I'm getting access to them like:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Computer1;
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Computer2;
```

But what if I want to access it by index like:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Computer[0];
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already made image name by using index.
So, you can access those files, like below,

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
{

  pictureBox1.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Computer" + i);

}
```

And, I'd like to recommend to read below articles.

[Load image from resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592150/load-image-from-resources)

[C# Resource Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536112/c-sharp-resource-array)