# C# set resource value based on method return value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I am trying to do something using Resource values but it isn't really working out for me at the moment. I currently have a Windows Forms application which uses a picturebox. I have two pictures set in my project resources ( X and Y ).

What i'm trying to achieve is the following :

```
pictureBoxTurn.Image = Properties.Resources.( either X or Y goes here hard-coded );
```

I have a method which returns X OR Y based on certain checks. I'm trying to put the return value up there instead of the hard-coded piece.

```
pictureBoxTurn.Image = Properties.Resources.( returned X/Y );
```

I was thinking about putting the return value in a local var, which I could use instead of the hard-coded piece. I'm sorry if I am being unclear but I have no idea on how to search for this problem. I tried, but simply enough couldn't find similar questions.

I'm still learning so my ways aren't perfect. Thank you for reading my question!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Resource Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536112/c-sharp-resource-array)

Comment: I've tried it. No errors, but no success either.

Comment: @Sochi If you have tried it and it didn't help, then post the code you tried and describe what and how fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string imageToReturn = GetImageToReturn();

object obj = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(imageToReturn, resourceCulture);
pictureBoxTurn.Image = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)obj;
```